# Highcharts: Custom Label Z-Index, Creating Multiple Labels

Tags: highcharts

I am using a custom label on an area graph.  Problem is that when the area is very large the custom label ends up behind the graph.  I am just testing using this as the label code:

```
    labels: {
        items : [{
            html : 'Center Me!<br>Row2',
            style : {
                left : '150px',
                top : '150px',
                fontSize : '20px'
            }
        }]
    }
```

Is there a way to get it so the custom label is always on top of the graph.
Also, as a second question -- is there a way to create multiple labels? If so what would be the syntax for that?

Comment: Could you reproduce your example in the jsfiddle.net?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5BxRh/

Comment: You can reproduce with example above depending on the width of the window. I wanst sure how to center image without using pixels.

Comment: Sebastian, were you able to look at the jsfiddle to see if you could reproduce?

Comment: Have you tried to set maxPadding?

Comment: Where would i add it? tried adding it to the style within my items but got an "unexpected identifier" error in console.

Comment: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.maxPadding